# What is the default Web Server for Chicago Boss?

Tags: chicagoboss

[**`Chicago Boss`**](http://www.chicagoboss.org/) is a great Erlang Framework. It ships with many dependecies including `mochiweb`, `yaws`, and `misultin`. After installation, Chicago Boss runs a development server very well.
I need to know which of the web servers it ships with, does it use by default ?  and how can i change from one web server to another without compromising my Chicago Boss project ?

Comment: why would some one down vote this question ? and forgets to add a comment ?!!! come on...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [CB Wiki](https://github.com/evanmiller/ChicagoBoss/wiki/Configuration):

> All configuration takes place in **boss.config** in your project directory....
>
> Webserver
>
> - port - The port to run the server on. Defaults to 8001.
> - server - The HTTP server to use. Valid values are:
>
>   - mochiweb - The Mochiweb Web Server
>   - misultin - The Misultin Web Server

So check in boss.config for which web server you use.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Misultin have been discontinued so I would avoid that one